# How can I target an id inside an specific class?

Tags: javascript, dom, towers-of-hanoi

I am constructing a Hanoi Tower, but I'm coming across problems involving parenting elements. I am trying to move the disks using remove a child and append child. Every tower and disk has an ID, but when I try to target a tower ID I get a disk ID.

```
<body>
    <article class="container"></article>
    <section class="towers">
        <div class="tower" id="towerOne">
            <div class="disk" id="diskOne"></div>
            <div class="disk" id="diskTwo"></div>
            <div class="disk" id="diskThree"></div>
            <div class="disk" id="diskFour"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tower" id="torreTwo"></div>
        <div class="tower" id="torreThree"></div>
    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>


const container = document.querySelector(".container")
const towers = document.querySelectorAll(".tower")
const disks = document.querySelectorAll(".disk")

let chosenDisc = ""
let chosenTower = ""

towers.forEach(choice => choice.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    chosenTower = e.target.id
}))

disks.forEach(choices => choices.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    chosenDisc = e.target
    chosenTower.removeChild(chosenDisc) 
    container.appendChild(chosenDisc)
}))
```

I did not put all IDs selections there, just classes to not long too much, but they are just the name plus numbers.

Comment: I've trying it
if (e.target.className === "tower") {
        chosenTower = e.target.id
    }

Comment: What does the HTML document / document structure look like?

Comment: Please create a snippet inside your question (using toolbar in editor) which we can run to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`chosenTower` is a string and you need to convert it as [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) while `chosenDisc` is a [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object because `e.target` return [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object. You can use `querySelector` function to convert it an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) like following

You should replace

```
chosenTower = e.target.id
```

to

```
chosenTower = document.querySelector('#' + e.target.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way out is to ask JS for parent element of Disk ID like this:

```
disks.forEach((choice) =>
  choice.addEventListener(
  "click",
   (e) => {
       chosenDisk = e.target.id;
       chosenTower = e.target.parentElement.id;
       console.log(chosenDisk, " is in ", chosenTower);
     },
   )
);
```